# Can't delete pm2 service because of the -- name

Tags: pm2

I'm trying to delete a service with `np2 delete <name>` but I'm getting this error because somehow by a mistake I have put two `--` before my service and now mp2 thinks I'm invoicing a command and doesn't work.

Error:

```
root@mt:~/mt-server# pm2 delete --mt

  error: unknown option `--mtium'

root@mt:~/mt-server#
```

[image: image of terminal]

Answer (score 2):

I assume that quoting the name will work:

```
pm2 delete '--muslimtab'
```

but you can just use the ID instead

```
pm2 delete 0
```